# Find minimum value of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a statement to find a user with minimum value of special field.
I mean something like this

```
Select ID, Username, Joindate, MIN(score) 
from table1
```

Actually I'm looking for a way to find a user with lowest score.

Answer (score 2):

To find the user with the lowest score, you can simpy sort the table and take the first record:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, UserName, JoinDate, score FROM table1 ORDER BY score
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this result a few different ways.

Subquery:

```
Select t1.ID,
  t1.Username,
  t1.Joindate,
  t1.Score
from table1 t1
inner join
(
  select min(score) LowestScore
  from table1
) t2
  on t1.score = t2.lowestscore
```

[`TOP WITH TIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
select top 1 with ties id, username, joindate, score
from table1
order by score
```

You could even use [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) to get the result:

```
select id, username, joindate, score
from
(
  select id, username, joindate, score,
    rank() over(order by score) rnk
  from table1
) src
where rnk = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3398b/6) of all queries.

Each of these will return all users with the lowest score.

Answer (score 1):

The Query can be -

```
Select ID,Username,Joindate,score from table1 
where score in (select MIN(score) from table1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select top 1 ID, Username, Joindate, score
from table1 where score = (select min(score) from table1)